# Cannot implicitly convert 'SoapService.Oferta[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SoapService.Oferta>'

Tags: c#, wcf, controller, visual-studio-2013

I have this error about a method that retrieves a list. Here is the code in which I used the method:

```
namespace MyApplication.Controllers
{
    [Authorization.ClientAuthorization(Roles = "Admin", ViewName = "Error")]
    public class ServiceController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetOfertaSOAP()
        { 
            SoapService.Service1Client client = new SoapService.Service1Client()
            List<SoapService.Oferta> lst = client.GetOferta();  
            return View("GetOfertaSOAP", lst);
        } 

    }
}
```

Now the error that I get is the following one:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyApplication.SoapService.Oferta[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyApplication.SoapService.Oferta>'
```

And the definition code for the method is this one:

```
public MyApplication.SoapService.Oferta[] GetOferta() 
{
    return base.Channel.GetOferta();
}
```

In the code, the error refers to client.GetOferta(); (this is the part underlined). What should I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the service returns an arry of the Oferta objects, you can use the [Enumerable.ToList`<TSource>`()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Like:

```
    public ActionResult GetOfertaSOAP()
    { 
        SoapService.Service1Client client = new SoapService.Service1Client()
        List<SoapService.Oferta> lst = client.GetOferta().ToList();  
        return View("GetOfertaSOAP", lst);
    }
```

If are targeting .NET framework < 3.5 you can use the [overloaded constructor of List`<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like:

```
    public ActionResult GetOfertaSOAP()
    { 
        SoapService.Service1Client client = new SoapService.Service1Client()
        List<SoapService.Oferta> lst = new List<SoapService.Oferta>(client.GetOferta());
        return View("GetOfertaSOAP", lst);
    }
```